# SearchKit - Unable to get a sample app working

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, searchkit

I've installed searchkit (https://github.com/searchkit/searchkit) and have been trying to just get a basic webpage to show something.  I have very little experience with Javascript and web development in general and would appreciate some help and guidance.

I installed SearchKit via bower and then simply copied out the bundle.js and theme.css into my project, just to see it work.

I have the following directory structure:

```
appHome/
       index.html
       js/
           searchkitbundle.js
           bundle.js
       css/
           theme.css
```

I copied bundle.js and theme.css from the release directory of the bower installation.  I copied searchkitbundle.js from the from the live editor on SearchKit's docs website (http://docs.searchkit.co/stable/docs/setup/project-setup.html).

Here is my index.html code:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/react/0.14.7/react.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/react/0.14.7/react-dom.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/searchkit/0.10.0/bundle.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/searchkit/0.10.0/theme.css">

    <title>JSP Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bundle.js"></script>
    <div id="app">
        <div class="search">
            <div class="search__query">
                <SearchBox/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

I have tried changing this in a variety of ways but can't get it to work.  It worked once, but I can't seem to get it to do so again.

I don't see any errors, either in the browser or in my IDE.  I'm deploying this locally as well as another copy of it within a Tomcat JSP application.

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong here and get it to work?

Comment: Are you seeing any errors in the error console?

Comment: In the browser?  No, I'm not.

Comment: Did you try this? https://github.com/searchkit/searchkit-starter-app